# Is there a word for immediate future just like "just" for immediate past?

Tags: phrase-usage

Let's say, Someone asks me

> Are you having dinner right now?

But right now I have an important call to make, so I say

> Not right now but I will have it in 4-5 minutes.

Even though I say 4-5 minutes, I don't mean it literally. I want to say that I have got something to do but it would hardly take any time, so even though It is not **right now** per se but not after very long time also.

What world can I use to say equivalent of 4-5 minutes?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In US English (I cannot speak to British) the equivalent would be *just about to*:

> ***Q:*** Have you had dinner yet?
> ***A:*** Yes, I've just finished it.
>
> ***Q:*** Are you having dinner right now?
> ***A:*** No, but I'm just about to.

Comment: This is completely normal in British English also.

Answer (score 7):

There are the idioms

> [***just a minute***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/just+a+minute), ***just a second***, or ***just a moment***
>   which mean *to wait a short period of time*
>
> **Q:** Are you having dinner right now?
>   **A:** No, It'll be ready in a minute.   (not a literal minute, but a brief period of time)
>
> **Q:** Are you ready for dinner now?
>   **A:** No, but I will be in just a moment.
>
> "Let's get in the car."
>   "Just a sec, I forgot the tickets."  (*second* is often shortened to *sec* in this spoken phrase)

Answer (score 6):

You'd have to say *very soon*, and you'd normally use it with a progressive construction:

> Not right now, but I'll be having it very soon.

*Shortly* is an alternative, but that may be a feature only of British English, and it may not always be appropriate.

Comment: Americans understand and use *shortly* (although I wouldn't be surprised if it were more common in the U.K.).

Comment: @Peter Shor. Doesn't AmEng also use _momentarily_ to mean 'in the very near future'?

Comment: Yes, *momentarily* also works in AmEng (although you may get grammar pedants telling you it's wrong).

Comment: If we're to believe [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be+here+shortly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) for *be here **shortly***, it would seem Americans use the term about as often as Brits.

Answer (score 3):

Adjective *[imminent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/imminent#Adjective)* (“about to happen, occur, or take place very soon”) may serve, or its adverbial form *[imminently](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/imminently)* (“In an imminent manner”).  But be careful not to confuse *imminent* with  *[eminent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eminent#Adjective)* (“noteworthy, remarkable, great; distinguished, important, noteworthy”) or with  *[immanent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/immanent#Adjective)* (“Naturally part of something; existing throughout and within something; inherent; integral; intrinsic; indwelling”).

If you don't mind a little confusion and ambiguity, you can use  *[presently](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/presently#Adverb)* in its sense “Before long; soon”.  It also has a sense  “At the present time; now; currently”, so its meaning is context sensitive.  For example, “Not right now, but presently” means “Not right now, but soon”, while “Not right now, but presently, presently” means “When I get good and ready”.

Comment: I understand *presently* to be a lot further off than *imminently*, *immediately*, *very soon*, or *shortly*, although not as far off as *eventually*.

Comment: I'm having trouble comprehending your last sentence. What does this mean? `while “Not right now, but presently, presently” means “When I get good and ready”.` The two "presently"s next to each other doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @WendiKidd, repeating a word like that can mean the speaker is chiding the questioner; ie, is saying “Hold your horses, don't be in such a rush”.  This is so when it's spoken in a certain tone of voice; but I agree that in general and without context it might not make sense to a reader.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **shortly** to describe the near future

> ***Q:*** Are you having dinner right now?
>   ***A:*** I'll have dinner shortly.

Answer (score 2):

As a British English speaker the most natural way for me to specify "the next few minutes" is to use "**in a minute**" (if you wanted to be specific and you literally meant one minute later you would say "**in one minute**").

Examples:

*"I'll tidy my room in a minute"*

*"Your dinner will be on the table in a minute"*

*"I'll be with you in a minute"*

You can also use "**momentarily**" in this context, especially in a formal situation.

*"Dr Anderson will be with you momentarily"* would be typical usage.

Answer (score 0):

The word, ***almost***, when applied to a future event, conveys that you will be doing it soon.

> I'm almost ready for dinner... I just have to finish writing this e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s how I would answer your question:

> “Yes, I’m just about to have my dinner.”
>
> “Not yet, but soon.”
>
> “Maybe later.”
>
> “Right after I finish my work.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: ***I just*** is to past as ***I'm about to*** is to future.

> ***Q:*** Have you had dinner yet?
> ***A:*** Yes, I just finished it.
>
> ***Q:*** Are you having dinner right now?
> ***A:*** No, but I'm about to.

You can also say "No, but I will in a little bit." or "No, but I will in a few minutes."

Comment: This is merely a combination of two previous answers.

Comment: No, other answers say "I've just" instead of "I just" and "I'm just about" instead of "I'm about".